# Graph Layout that honors edge weights

Tags: jgrapht, jgraph

I am using JGraph 5.13 with jgrapht 0.9.0. I was wondering if there is a layout that honors edge weights so if a edge has weight 500 then it appears 5 times longer than a edge with weight 100 and also a layout that tries to put maximum distance between the node?

Comment: Note that, in the general case, it might be impossible to draw a graph with edge_weigth=edge_length. For example: A->B (w=1), A->C (w=1), B->C (w=100). See [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Yes I see the inequality but what if the graph is guaranteed to not have such inequalities?